# Create runnable jar with RXTX jar and DLL

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, jar

I am using RXTX jar to read from serial port and process the information in java. i already copied the required `.dll` files to `programFiles/jdk/jre/bin/` ..

The program works and read from the serail por when i run it from eclipse. However nothing happens when i export the project into a runnable jar file.

any advise on what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

finally found the solution [here](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Deploying_JAVA_with_RXTX)

used the Janel JAVA launcher.